# json error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: swift

I am building a photo browser for Instagram. I don't have any runtime errors or crashes but evidently the logic in my getPath function block needs work because NSError is saying

> json error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

I have checked similar SO questions with the error but they are more json syntax centric and/or discuss array objects to which I don't how they apply to my code.

My do catch seems to be ok but I need help with data acquisition.

```
func get(path: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: path)
    lastSearchURL = path

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        print("Task completed")
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            //self.delegate?.didFailToGetMedia?(error!)

                let results: NSArray = jsonResult["data"] as! NSArray
                self.delegate?.didFetchMediaItems?(results)

        } catch let error {
            print("json error: \(error)")
        }

        })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: The error message is saying that the returned `data` is not in a valid JSON format. What do you get putting `print(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))` before your `do ` ?

Comment: I got tons of json/html? data. Looks like Instagram html.

Comment: Maybe HTML. Isn't that some sort of error pages?

Comment: Without complete path and parameters, you cannot get APIs to work. Try input that URL into your browser, you'll see some error page saying "Sorry, this page isn't available."

Comment: You may need to visit [Instagram Developer](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) pages first. Using APIs is not so simple.

Comment: You can make it yourself. (Or someone else would do.) I will try to get "correct" mark in the future, maybe in another thread. Good luck for you and for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it has to do with my API set up. This tutorial is very good.
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/instagram

```
let baseURL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=1234567.d7e73cc.cces4f9532ba442529270d698fb173cc"
let popularEndpoint = "media/popular"
let clientID = "d5e23bhb23414e569480724305d3f104"
```

Comment: Strange though.  Xcode still telling me my token is invalid. I triple checked.

Answer (score 0):

actually it's a server side issue. ie, the response is neither in array nor Dictionary,

so please ask the backend team to fix the error  :)